# Finding the Nth number where a given binary digit is set to 0

Tags: algorithm, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, bit

I am looking for an algorithm which given a target, the Nth number with that target bit at 0 is returned.

For example, for the inputs of `n={0,1,2,3}` and `target=1`,
The output would be (in binary)

`000,001,100,101`

Comment: If performance is not an issue, for each `N` in `n` you check the target bit until N is 0(only decrement if target bit is 0) at which point that would be the Nth number. You could store intermediate results, and use those in subsequent traversals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target bit oscillates between being unset `target**2` times and set `target**2` times, as we move up the sequence of natural numbers. So we can directly calculate the `n`th number where the target bit is unset.

JavaScript code:

```js
function f(n, target){
    let block = 1 << target
    
    if (n < block)
      return n
      
    let index_in_block = n % block;
    let num_set_blocks = (n - index_in_block) / block
      
    return 2 * num_set_blocks * block + index_in_block
}

for (let i=0; i<10; i++)
  console.log(i, f(i, 1))
```

Answer (score 3):

Just write the value `N-1` *(if enumeration starts from 1)* in binary, and then insert a `0` in the required position (`target`).

For example:

```
 for N=3 and target=1 
 N-1 = 10bin
 inserting 0 in 1-th position gives 
 R = 100b = 4dec
```

with bit operations:

```
 NN = N- 1
 Mask = (1 << target) - 1   //like 00000111 for target=3
 NotMask = ~ Mask           //like 11111000 for target=3 
 R = (NN & Mask) | ((NN & NotMask) << 1)
```

expression `(NN & Mask)` selects bits right to target bit (zeroing other bits)
expression `(NN & NotMask) << 1` selects left bits, then shifts them to free a place for zero target bit